# How to convert list to multiple Q objects?

Tags: django

Taking an [example from Django 3.2 documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects), I need to use an argument like this for `.filter`:

`Q(question__startswith='Who') | Q(question__startswith='What')`

In my case need to convert each of the user's selections, which I'm getting in views.py via `request.META['QUERY_STRING']`, into it's own `Q()` object.

If I tried to create Q objects from that list of parameters, it would not work, because the `|` would be evaluated. This seems like it must be a solved a problem, but I haven't had luck yet finding the answer. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build up a complex `Q` object in a loop - use `q_obj |= Q(...)` to add another `Q` with OR

```
selections = ['Who', 'What']
or_expr = Q()
for selection in selections:
    or_expr |= Q(question__startswith=selection)
MyModel.objects.filter(or_expr)
```

Comment: I didn't think this would work, but it did. Thank you, its exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

using regex might be an easy option:

```
Model.objects.filter(question__iregex="^(What|Who).*")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using distnict()

```
.filter(Q(question__startswith='Who') | Q(question__startswith='What')).distnict()
```